# How do I copy a fixed cell into the outermost empty cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy a fixed column range (D20:D39) into an empty column, say K20:K39. The columns keeps getting updated every time I update (D20:D39), i.e. K, L, M, N... will get updated when I want to copy (D20:D39) over. I am not proficient in coding or computer science and just trying to make my spreadsheet efficient. Any one able to help?

I've looked at some other threads but mostly mentioned copying into a separate worksheet. None mentioned this "rolling" copy n paste mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will calculate the last column used (in row 20, since we'll be copying to there) then will set the column values one column over to the same ones as range D20 to D39:

```
Sub coppercopy()
Dim lastcol As Integer

lastcol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(20, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(20, lastcol + 1), Cells(39, lastcol + 1)).Value = Range("D20:D39").Value

Range(Cells(42, lastcol + 1), Cells(32, lastcol + 1)).Value = Range("D42:D62").Value
End Sub
```

If you want to copy and paste instead of setting the values to be the same as the range, use this:

```
Sub coppercopy()
Dim lastcol As Integer
lastcol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(20, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range("D20:D39").copy
Cells(20, lastcol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Edit, the first option is edited to include more ranges. This can be done on the same line, but for code readability and ease of use I've put it on a new line. Please note that the `Cells(` statement always takes an R1C1 notation, unlike the `Range(` statement. Meaning it references to `Cells(Row number, Column number)`. Keeping this in mind this can be easily updated to include any range to be copied as well by updating to the correct cell reference.

**Second edit:**
As per the comments, the range needs to be more dynamic while still getting rid of the `sum` formula when copying. The following sub is adapted to this. It will copy the entire range starting from D20 to the last filled row, and copies it into the next available column as needed. It  then loops over the entire copied range **+1** (This is to account for a `sum` formula at the end of the range which needs to be deleted) and if blanks are found (indicating a new "paragraph") it deletes the cell above (always the `sum` formula for the last paragraph).

```
Sub coppercopy()
Dim lastcol As Integer, lastr As Integer, cel As Range

lastcol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(20, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'determine last column with values
lastr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'determine last row with values

Range(Cells(20, lastcol + 1), Cells(lastr, lastcol + 1)).Value = Range("D20:D" & lastr).Value 'copy range to column after last used one

For Each cel In Range(Cells(20, lastcol + 1), Cells(lastr + 1, lastcol + 1)) 'If the copied range does not end with a sum formula, omit the `+ 1` after `lastr`.
    If cel.Value = "" Then 'loops over all cells and checks for blanks
        cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "" 'if blank is found, delete cell above
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! your first option works wonders.However, if I want to do the same action for Range("D20:D39"), Range("D42:D62"), Range("D64:D84"), i.e. copy the values in these ranges over to Range("K20:K39"), Range("K42:K62"), Range("K64:K84"), would you happen to know how? Otherwise, I can just use your code separately for each of the ranges. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @rachely if you repeat the last sentence (starting with `range(cells`) and update the numbers in it to match the new range you should be OK. If that is the only range you copy though make sure to also update the number in the lastcol statement to be included in the range.

Comment: @RachelY I have also updated my answer to demonstrate what I've done, and how I've done what you requested.

Comment: @RachelY No problem, happy to help. Feel free to ask any more questions you might have, or mark my answer as accepted if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi Plutian, guess i didnt foresee this problem earlier and sorry to bother again. Right now the code works for Range("D20:D39"), Range("D42:D62"), Range("D64:D84"). But if I add rows, say one row between D38:D39, then all the subsequent rows get shifted down and the code won't work since it fixed the rows. Do you know how to make this more dynamic so that it includes the shifting of rows? thanks!!

Comment: @RachelY this can be done, but it won't be as straightforward as the above. You'll need to identify the data you want to copy within the code. Can I ask what is in the cells you're omitting above, range D39 to D42? Are they blank?

Comment: The content of D39 to D42 is partly blank and partly formula. I can't post a screenshot here otherwise it'd be so much easier to understand.  In D38:39 currently there's content as values. In D40:41 these are empty rows. and in D42 is a row of the SUM formula linked to D43:63.  The sequence of my worksheet goes like this: SUM formula > 20 rows of values > 2 rows of blank > SUM formula > 20 rows of values > 2 rows of blank etc...

Comment: If the cells you want to omit are blanks with one being a formula. Could you not just copy over the entire column instead, including the gaps? Or do you want to make sure the SUM formula is cut out?

Comment: Thats right, I want to cut out the SUM formula. The other problem is if I add a row among the 20 rows of values e.g. between D38:39, the whole workbook gets shifted down by 1 row, so D43:D63 actually gets shifted down to D44:D64. However the code has already fixed D43:63. This fixation causes the copy n paste to show in the wrong column, so wondering if there's a dynamic way that without fixing or hardcoding the cell reference, the code still works if I add rows. Hope this clarifies my question!

Comment: @RachelY I've updated my answer to do what you requested above, and explained what it does. Please let me know if this is correct.